# Django Model field isn't visible in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

Django admin isn't showing category field
I have Model

```py
class UserCart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menu_item = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menu_item_quantity = models.SmallIntegerField(max_length=2),
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'menu_item')
```

And I have also registered in admin.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category, MenuItem, Order, OrderItem, UserCart
(...)
admin.site.register(UserCart)
```

but Django admin shows only user, menu item, unit price, and price field

How can i fix it

Answer (score 0):

Fix it, it was just a comma, at the end of menu_item_category field that was causing the issue